# MySQL - Trying to filter out date and time that is past current time

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause

So, I have a set of leave requests that is being loaded in from my database

```
SELECT ID, name, email, startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime, reason, specialLeave 
FROM request 
WHERE requestStatus = 'In behandeling'
```

I am trying to filter that query. Specifically, I want to compare startDate and startTime to the current time. I want it to be visible when the start date is today or later, and the starttime isn't reached yet. I've tried multiple things like concat, now(), curtime(), curdate().

I've gotten as far as getting it to filter the startDate with the following :

```
SELECT ID, name, email, startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime, reason, specialLeave 
FROM request 
WHERE requestStatus = 'In behandeling' AND CURDATE() <= startDate
```

But I am not sure how to go from here, any tips?

Comment: I think you need use `betwen` for example `startDate between (curdate()-1, curdate()+1)`

Comment: The date works great the way it is, Im trying to add the time in to the equation.

Comment: You run query directly or use ORM? better get currentDateTime from php

Comment: The PHP part of this appears to be irrelevant, since it isn't changing the content of the query. Edited to refocus on purely SQL

Comment: Anyway can you please show a sample of the data in the table, and what result you'd expect from your query when filtering that data, and also a CREATE TABLE statement so we can see the data types being used for each column? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) function with `startDate` and `startTime` as arguments to return `DATETIME` of these columns and compare it to [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

```
TIMESTAMP(startDate, startTime) > NOW()
```

Comment: I misread the question. This is the correct (and simple) solution.

Comment: No problem, Thanks for trying to help!